# Paragraph Tags are not Functioning As Expected

Tags: css, list, paragraph

Thanks in advance for any help here.

I have a sandbox and a live site that I'm making some minor tweaks to. There's one section that I just can't figure out what's causing the issue. Photos below.

Inside a li there's menu items that have a title, description and price. In some instances there's no price for the item and when that field is empty in the CMS the lines style themselves differently.

Here is the way I want it to appear: Live Site: https://www.crownshy.nyc/menus/#cocktails

[cocktails page non-alc with no prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iYTv.jpg)

The following is the way it's populating on the sandbox: https://crownshy-sandbox.getbento.com/menus/#cocktails

[Sandbox cocktails page non-alc no prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEfnD.jpg)

There's really nothing special about the code here, which is why I'm a bit confused. I just need to take a break and come back with a fresh eye but hoping you all can speed this along. I'm happy to post the CSS but figure because it's several classes that it would be easier to look at it on the developer console

```html
<section class="menu-section">
  <div class="menu-section__header">
    <h2>Non-Alcoholic</h2>

  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <p class="menu-item__heading">No Mas</p>
      <p>Pear, Citrus, Rose, Lemon, Yogurt</p>
      <p class="menu-item__details menu-item__details--price">
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <p class="menu-item__heading">Ginger Jammer</p>
      <p>Ginger, Mango, Togarashi, Lime, Soda</p>
      <p class="menu-item__details menu-item__details--price">
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <p class="menu-item__heading">Hojito</p>
      <p>Hoja Santa, Lime, Tonic, Seasonal Herbs</p>
      <p class="menu-item__details menu-item__details--price">
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Sandbox the heading appears to be missing a width.

```
    p.menu-item__heading {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: how come that overrides the paragraph html to break the line?

Comment: Glad that helped. It's not overriding display:inline-block. The width:100% forces the heading to fill the container. The width isn't needed if the heading is changed to display:block; which forces the other <p>'s to move below it.

Answer (score -1):

You put the style on span tag of on live site with this class name `.menu-item__currency`

You can use that class name or you can put a new tag and add `float:left` property with that class, I think then the issue will resolve.